# Nested resource and restricting the Routes Created :only and :except

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, nested-resources, nested-routes

Good day all,

Can someone kindly assist me with nested resources and its best practice.

I would like to restrict my `:events` route to only `:show` and `:index`, is this the correct way of doing it?

```
resources :events do
    resources :registrations, :except => [:index]
end

resources :events, :only => [:index, :show]
```

Is this the best way or the way more Rubyist would handle such thing? I've added two lines of `resources :events` or is there a way to combine it all in 1 block?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes. You can combine it in one block like:

```
resources :events, only: [:index, :show] do
    resources :registrations, except: :index
end
```

Comment: Sergey, you sir, are one lovely person. Thank you so much.